# are there feature differences in c# and vb for excel plugins?

Tags: visual-studio, excel

I am creating an excel plugin for the first time. Visual Studio gives 2 options to create an excel plugin: VB or C#. I don't know either language. Are there any limitations w/ either when creating excel plugins? I just don't want to get too far into the project and then realize that only VB will do this and/or only C# will do that...in other words, can I create ALL the same functionality w/ a VB excel plugin as w/ a C# excel plugin?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I guess that's another question...I'm using version 4...this plugin will be available to anyone to download once I'm done...will using version 4 create compatibility problems?

Comment: Well, anyone who doesn't have version 4 installed will not be able to use it (though you _can_ re-target the version in Visual Studio 2010 projects).

Comment: what do "most" people have? what do you recommend I use? The plugin won't be too crazy...just pulling values from a mysql database

Comment: No idea what "most" people have. You should poll the target users to see what versions the mostly have.

Comment: .Net 3.5 is included inside Windows 7. You can see the defaults here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **No**, there are no limitations.

In .Net, you can choose to code in VB.net or C#. They are both CLR languages. Before C# 4.0, COM Interop was simply easier to work with using VB.Net, but now they are both just fine. It boils down to personal choice. Choose one and try it out! ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know either of these languages and need to decide which one to learn, definitely go for C#.  It is just a better language, hands down.  While I don't know an answer to the specific question you are asking, I'm certain that if there are any differences (which is very unlikely), it would be in favor of C#.